# Browser Sync Error - 'Cannot GET/'

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

I'm currently using Browser Sync newest version (2.24.6) installed via `npm install -g browser-sync` and I did so in my `C:\Users\USERNAME\Google Drive` I am using Gulp.

I start browser sync by running `browser-sync start --server --files '*.html, css/*.css, js/*.js'` in bash and my project opens up.  The project updates as expected when I change HTML, CSS, and/or JS files.

However, when I edit my `package.json` file (which is not in the same directory) under "scripts" with `"start": browser-sync start --server --files '*.html, css/*.css, js/*.js'` and then run `npm start` in my bash console I get a page but all I see is `Cannot GET /` and not my project.

Also, if I try to `browser-sync start --server --files '*.html, css/*.css, js/*.js'` or in any other project I get the same error.

If I do `gulp browser-sync` this is what I get:

```html
[06:03:14] Working directory changed to ~\Google Drive
[06:03:15] Using gulpfile ~\Google Drive\gulpfile.js
[06:03:15] Starting 'browser-sync'...
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.116:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.1.116:3001
 --------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
```

Here is my `gulpfile.js` :

```js
const gulp = require("gulp");
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
  browserSync.init({
     server: {
        baseDir: './',
     }
  });
});
```

And here is my `package.json` file:

```js
{
  "name": "eslint-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.24.6",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.18.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.9.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "browser-sync start --server --files '*.html, css/*.css, js/*.js'"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I apologize if this is not the right place but I have searched and watched videos for about 2 hours with no answers found.  I appreciate any and all help/links.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions on this?

Comment: 5 days and no responses?  Anyone have any suggestions on this?

Comment: Do you have an index.html file? Or are you calling it something else? If so, you need to tell BrowserSync what your index file is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BrowserSync Cannot GET /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962528/browsersync-cannot-get)